# I Use Storage Access Framework to browse a file link f.cfg, when you select the file, the app need to load another file like f.dat automatically, how?

Tags: android, uri, saf

In Android Studio:

This app must use COMTRADE files. The COMTRADE files are *.cfg *.dat and *.rio files. For example, (user.cfg, user.dat and user.rio). The main file is *.cfg file, so the user must browse by SAF to find *.cfg files, when the user select this file, the app must load other files ( *.dat and *.rio) automatically.

I can not use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` for android level 30

So I have to use Storage Access Framework, By below code the user browse *.cfg files and select a file like user.cfg

```
if(SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
{

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   intent.setType("*/*");

   Act.startActivityForResult(intent, 111);

}
else
{...}
```

Then SAF return URI of that user.cfg file, and the app does not have any URI of other files to load.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(requestCode == 111)
   {
    
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
      {
    
         if (data != null)
         {
    
            try 
            {
    
               Uri uri = null;
               uri = data.getData();
    
               InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                            
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

               // I want URI of user.dat how?
                            
               InputStreamReader inputStreamReader1 = new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri1));
                            
               BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader1);
    
               ....
                        
               }  
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

            }           

         }
    
      }

   }

}
```

Please help me how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me how can I do this?

You cannot do this, at least by means of using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, unless you ask the user to open each of your three documents in turn. Just because the user selected a `.cfg` file does not mean that you have any rights to any other files, including those adjacent to it.

You could try using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the user choose the document tree that contains your desired files. From there, you can:

- Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing the tree
- Call `listFiles()` on that `DocumentFile` to get the direct contents of that tree, in the form of a list of `DocumentFile` objects
- Call `getName()` on each of those to get their display names, then see which names have your desired file extensions and matching base names (`foo.cfg` and `foo.rio` and `foo.dat`)
- For those that you want to use, call `getUri()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a `Uri` to use with `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I think, First I have to list all cfg files in a folder like Downloads folder, then the user select a cfg file, and then the app find other files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I get list of files in a folder like Download folder By SAF or anything else? I do not want the user to select download folder, I want to do this first by the app.

Comment: The user should select the folder if your app uses ACTION_OPEN_DOCEMENT_TREE. Since Android R/11 the Download directory can not be choosen.